# Javascript Bookmarklet Get Url Variable, Open Multiple Search Windows

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I tried for months to build this myself before asking but at this stage I'm forced to accept that I will only ever be the worst kind of code-stealing script-kiddie and am terrible at javascript.

Confession over, I need a single bookmarklet that when run, will get 1 variable from the URL (i.e. q=2075083, ALWAYS a 7 digit number, q will always be the id), open 2 new tabs, each one using the variable grabbed to perform a custom search in each of the other two tabs.

There's only one more caveat - I will need to add more search tabs in the future :/

And I'm LOST trying to make it myself. Can anyone lend their expertise or advice?

This is an operation I perform hundreds of times a day, and it would significantly reduce the amount of mouse clicks and copy-paste operations I'll do.

Thank you dearly to anyone who can help or advise.

P.S. I've gotten as far as the code below (which I'll make in to a bookmarklet at a later stage).

```
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}
```

Calling getQueryVariable("q") returns the number I need, but I've no idea how to put it to use creating the two other tabs searching for it.

Comment: Down-voting my request for help without any criticism isn't very helpful.

Comment: Can you show your current progress? Do you have a working Javascript function that can to the job when passed a url?

Comment: I've updated the posting with the code I've gotten so far. No idea how to put it to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
javascript:var q=document.location.href.match(/q=(.*?)(?=&|$)/i);if(!q)alert('q not found');else {q=q[1];window.open('http://google.com/search?q='+q);window.open('http://bing.com/search?q='+q)}
```

Replace google.com and bing.com with your choices.

Add another `window.open(...)` for additional tabs.

(Since you are new to this site, don't forget to click the green checkbox to accept an answer.)

Comment: I love you DG. That worked FLAWLESSLY. My mind is blown, to say the least, and I am FOREVER grateful!!!!!!!

Comment: Hey DG, thanks again for this answer. I was hoping you might have a quick look at it again for me as I tried using this script in Firefox but when run the original window changes to say `[object Window]`. Any ideas?

Comment: Add `void(0);` at the end. (If interested for details, check my history. I answered a related question in recent history but don't have time now to find it.)

Comment: I can't thank you enough, this has been invaluable all along and I use it tens of times a day!